# GIT committing more than it needs to

Tags: git

Whenever I commit the below project, it will always update the highlighted files too. I understand that they are changing each time but I'm not convinced they're required for others to contribute to the code. I've cloned a few different times and always have the same result. My other main project always will just commit the code changes I make.

Currently I cannot collaborate with others on this project as each time there is merge issues which are beyond my comprehension. Does anyone know how I can get it to ignore these from the start? Using ignore commands feels like a plaster over what should be a simple solution.

Thank you.

[image: git diff]

Comment: If these are flies that belong to the build, probably you have to add them (or the whole build directories) to `.gitignore` and remove from git?

Comment: also, if it looks some random sync issue just try git clean and then work. Also as pointed by @DmitriyPopov, you can place in gitignore.